# Como obter a lista de ids de invoices associados a um dado customer party

Tags: api

Existe alguma API ou método no Jasmin para obter a lista de ids de invoices dado o `partyKey` (preferencialmente) ou o `id` de um customer party?

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar queries odata para aplicar os filtros que pretende:

Exemplos de chamadas:

```
{{url}}/api/{{tenant}}/{{organization}}/billing/invoices/odata?$filter=BuyerCustomerParty eq 'Party'

{{url}}/api/{{tenant}}/{{organization}}/billing/invoices/odata?$filter=BuyerCustomerPartyId eq Guid'1821efbd-6e01-4d00-964b-34c875a96b3c'
```